# Can I still plant Gladiolus in Zone 6a in late July?

Tags: bulbs

I came across some nice Gladiolus bulbs in the store. I see they already started to grow their roots and I wanted to know if I can still plant them, since they bloom till October, I think. I live New York, Zone 6a or 6b.

Comment: You might as well plant them anyway - they won't keep over the winter in a packet, and you just might get a flower or two before winter.

Answer (score 3):

I've done it - they flower before frost here in southeast Pennsylvania when planted that late, but they don't regrow a good corm, so you can't keep them over the winter very well.